# How to avoid this error and correctly test a Rails 3 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im developing some test cases to a very old legacy application running Rails 3.

I created a simple test here:

```
test/functional/transactions_controller.rb

require 'test_helper'

class TransactionsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
   test "the truth" do
     assert true
   end
  # test "product recycled is removed from the iventory" do
  #   assert true
  # end
end
```

I already run:

```
bundle exec rake db:create RAILS_ENV=test                                                                                                                                 
bundle exec rake db:schema:load RAILS_ENV=test
```

When I try to make my test with this command:

```
 ruby -Itest test/functional/transactions_controller_test.rb
```

I got this error:

```
TransactionsControllerTest
ERROR (0:00:00.089) the truth
  Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'shiped_at' in 'field list': INSERT INTO `bill_of_ladings` (`shiped_at`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `id`) VALUES ('2012-02-27 09:51:12', '2018-12-20 13:15:21', '2018-12-20 13:15:21', 980190962)
```

If I just comment in my test the "test the truth" line. It works (I was afraid that was something rellated to my environment).

```
This is my test/fixtures/bill_of_lading.yml


one:
  customer: 
  shiped_at: 2012-02-27 09:51:12

two:
  customer: 
  shiped_at: 2012-02-27 09:51:12
```

Well. My test doesnt do nothing, only an 'assert true'. Why the test case is trying to insert something in database? Am I missing something here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before running tests Rails loads fixtures from `test/fixtures/*.yml` (see more [in official guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.8/testing.html#the-low-down-on-fixtures)), from the error it can be seen that your fixtures are out of sync with your db schema and still have `shiped_at` column.

You can update fixtures to have correct data or remove them, if you do not use them.